# Magento 2 Product Collection displays query

Tags: php, mysql, magento, product, magento2

I am having this weird issue, Can someone please point out what i am doing wrong.

I want to display the products in a category related to position added in another table, with following columns

```
id, category_id, product_id, position
```

In my module i extended the \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct 
and \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar

In the ListProduct file, i override _getProductCollection method and add the following

```
$joinConditions = array();
            $joinConditions[] = 'e.entity_id = rs.product_id';
            $joinConditions[] = 'rs.category_id = ' . $category->getId();
            $this->_productCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                    ['rs' => 'my_new_table'], implode(' AND ', $joinConditions), ['position']
            );
```

And in the Toolbar i override setCollection method

```
switch ($this->getCurrentOrder())
        {
            case 'position':
                if ($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc')
                {
                    $this->_collection
                            ->getSelect()
                            ->order('rs.position DESC');
                } elseif ($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc')
                {
                    $this->_collection
                            ->getSelect()
                            ->order('rs.position ASC');
                }
                break;

            default:

                if ($this->getCurrentOrder())
                {
                    $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
                }
                break;
        }
```

I get the correct result, but FULL query gets displayed on all catalog pages. I have checked everywhere in my code. i do not print the query anywhere. The best part is if i change

```
case 'position':
                    if ($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc')
                    {
                        $this->_collection
                                ->getSelect()
                                ->order('rs.position DESC');
                    } elseif ($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc')
                    {
                        $this->_collection
                                ->getSelect()
                                ->order('rs.position ASC');
                    }
                    break;
```

TO

```
case 'position':
                    if ($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc')
                    {
                        $this->_collection
                                ->getSelect()
                                ->order('position DESC');
                    } elseif ($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc')
                    {
                        $this->_collection
                                ->getSelect()
                                ->order('position ASC');
                    }
                    break;
```

In the Toolbar class, removing 'rs' from order function. The order gets reverted to magento default position. but the query does not get displayed anymore

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I think,You should remove ->getSelect() from it and check again.